# How to remove browsers message "You need to upgrade your Flash Player" after 12 jan 2021

Tags: browser, flash-player

How to remove browsers message "You need to upgrade your Flash Player" after 12 jan 2021 .
according to this page :
https://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/end-of-life.html

we need patch for all versions of browsers .

Thanks
Saeed

Comment: "You need to upgrade your Flash Player" is for newer versions of browsers . We are speaking about new versions of browsers . old versions resolved there . but newer versions of browsers stoped working with flash player after 12 jan 2021 with that message.

Comment: We need to remove this new message :
"You need to upgrade your Flash Player"
in this topic.

Comment: You cannot remove that message. Flash is no longer able to be used, has been being phased out for the last 5 years at least, and has basically been unsupported for 5 to 10 years before that. The way to remove the message from that page specifically would be to buy out Adobe and force their engineers to begin working on Flash again.

Answer (score 0):

Usually that message was a phishing attempt to get you to download malware.

Now that Flash is thankfully gone forever, you now know you can always ignore it & not fall for the scam.

[image]

See https://www.pcrisk.com/removal-guides/10748-adobe-flash-player-update-scam